# ORA-01747 using Play framework

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I've been trying to get a native UPDATE query executed but I keep getting an ORA-01747 error.

```
public void editemployee (String id, String fname, String lname, String email, String phone,
        String hdate, String job, String salary, String comm, String dept) {
    StringBuilder editquery = new StringBuilder();
    editquery.append("UPDATE EMPLOYEES ");
    editquery.append("SET ");
    editquery.append("    FIRST_NAME = '"+fname+"', ");
    editquery.append("    LAST_NAME = '"+lname+"', ");
    editquery.append("    EMAIL = '"+email+"', ");
    editquery.append("    PHONE_NUMBER = '"+phone+"', ");
    editquery.append("    HIRE_DATE = TO_DATE('"+hdate+"', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), ");
    editquery.append("    SALARY = "+salary+", ");
    editquery.append("    COMMISSION_PCT = "+comm+", ");
    editquery.append("    JOB_ID = (SELECT JOB_ID FROM JOBS WHERE JOB_TITLE = '"+job+"'), ");
    editquery.append("    DEPARTMENT_ID = (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = '"+dept+"'), ");
    editquery.append("    MANAGER_ID = (SELECT MANAGER_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = '"+dept+"') ");
    editquery.append("WHERE ");
    editquery.append("    EMPLOYEE_ID = "+id);

    JPA.em().createNativeQuery(editquery.toString()).executeUpdate();
}
```

This is for a training activity, so we were required to use StringBuilders to format our queries as such.

Here's a part of the error logs from the console.

```
2016-08-19 16:16:45,054 - [INFO] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Application started (Dev)

2016-08-19 16:16:47,177 - [ERROR] - from org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter in play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-38 

ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification   

2016-08-19 16:16:47,178 - [ERROR] - from play in play-internal-execution-context-1 
Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query  
2016-08-19 16:16:47,181 - [ERROR] - from application in play-internal-execution-context-1
```

As for the database itself, the column names are correct, seeing as I was able to execute other native queries using these column names as well.

```
public void addemployee (String fname, String lname, String email, String phone,
        String hdate, String job, String salary, String comm, String dept) {
    StringBuilder addquery = new StringBuilder();
    addquery.append("INSERT INTO ");
    addquery.append("    EMPLOYEES( ");
    addquery.append("        EMPLOYEE_ID, ");
    addquery.append("        FIRST_NAME, ");
    addquery.append("        LAST_NAME, ");
    addquery.append("        EMAIL, ");
    addquery.append("        PHONE_NUMBER, ");
    addquery.append("        HIRE_DATE, ");
    addquery.append("        SALARY, ");
    addquery.append("        COMMISSION_PCT, ");
    addquery.append("        JOB_ID, ");
    addquery.append("        DEPARTMENT_ID, ");
    addquery.append("        MANAGER_ID ) ");
    addquery.append("VALUES ( ");
    addquery.append("   (SELECT max(EMPLOYEE_ID) FROM EMPLOYEES) + 1, ");
    addquery.append("   '"+fname+"', ");
    addquery.append("   '"+lname+"', ");
    addquery.append("   '"+email+"', ");
    addquery.append("   '"+phone+"', ");
    addquery.append("   TO_DATE('"+hdate+"', 'YYYY/MM/DD'), ");
    addquery.append("   "+salary+", ");
    addquery.append("   "+comm+", ");
    addquery.append("   (SELECT JOB_ID FROM JOBS WHERE JOB_TITLE = '"+job+"'), ");
    addquery.append("   (SELECT DEPARTMENT_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = '"+dept+"'), ");
    addquery.append("   (SELECT MANAGER_ID FROM DEPARTMENTS WHERE DEPARTMENT_NAME = '"+dept+"')) ");

    JPA.em().createNativeQuery(addquery.toString()).executeUpdate();
}
```

This particular INSERT query executes just fine, so I'm not entirely sure how and why I'm getting the ORA-01747 on the UPDATE query. I also tested both queries on my Oracle SQL Developer and they're both executing.

I did try to look around for similar questions, but most of what I saw were for INSERT queries, which made me all the more confused as to why the errors are occurring.

Comment: So, if you print the result of `editquery` right before making the query, copy the result and execute it in SQL DEveloper it works?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. It's what I usually do whenever I'm testing queries done with StringBuilder to check for missing spaces or separators. Only this time, it works in Developer but not in the actual program.